# How to access the documents on publishing site when using Cross Site Publishing in SharePoint 2013 for document library

Tags: document-library, cross-site-publishing

I can get Cross Site Publishing working with Page Library. When I set it up with document library, on the publishing site I can see the items, but when I click on the links, I either see some metadata (for a pdf file) or get "500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR" (for a Word docx file). I read that for Cross Site Publishing, you need to treat Document Library as Asset Library. Does anyone know an example of doing that?